# facebook authentication using javascript via Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to display a simple alert window using my chrome extension when a user is logged on to facebook. I have the javascript sdk initializing code  and also the code to get login status in my background.html page. My manifest.json file calls the background page correctly.

I am unable to place a breakpoint on the background.html page. I want to know if this is how i should go about declaring javascript facebook sdk and checking if a user is logged in.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : 'my App id (i have my app id)',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());

 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
          alert("logged in");} 
    else {
        // no user session available, someone you dont know                                                                                                            
    }
});

 </script>
```

Comment: Did you find the best way to do this? :)

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of issues in your code, lets fix it first and then explain:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'your app id',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        channelUrl : 'http://WWW.MYDOMAIN.COM/channel.html',
        oauth  : true
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
              alert("logged in");} 
        else {
            // no user session available, someone you dont know                                                                                                            
        }
    });
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Now the points to consider:

1. Read the [Javascript SDK documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)
2. Use the `oauth` flag to enable [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/)
3. You need to either use asynchronous loading or the standard method but not both of them (I'm loading it asynchronously here)
4. Put all your Facebook calls in the `fbAsyncInit`
5. Add a channel file
6. Read these articles [one](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/), [two](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-javascript-sdk-best-practices/58/)

Comment: hi ifaour, i implemented your recommendations other than the channel url since this is an add-on. But i still don't see this alert window when i am logged in to facebook. I also don't see 'fb-root' in my inspect element window.

Comment: the alert window appears if i call it outside Fb.getloginStatus()

Comment: can you try [this](http://codepad.org/Ip66G79A)? when I load this page while im logged in to Facebook I get the *logged in* alert.

Comment: No. I am running this code as background.html and also i get an error if i use document.location.protocol. So, i changed it to http:.  are u running it on chrome?

Comment: @Praveen: error?! no I'm not getting any errors and yes I'm testing it on Chrome. I guess the issue is not with the code itself.

Comment: hmm....this is very weird. Also, wat about using document.location.protocol?? the error is Get chrome-extension://connect.facebook.net........

Comment: Also, i cannot see fb-root div when i use the inspect element

Comment: hey i figured out this error when i was digging through this html code. I think this is the error for the e.src connect.facebook link. Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the Application configuration. It must match one of the Connect or Canvas URLs or domain must be the same as or a subdomain of one of the Application's base domains.    The url i specified is              e.src = 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';

Comment: @ifaur: hey when u test it with your application on facebook, do u have a canvas url or connect url or site domain or site url on your app's settings

Comment: of course I have a the Site URL set :-) I always develop and test locally so my Site URL looks like: http://localhost/my_app/

Comment: @Praveen let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2545/discussion-between-ifaour-and-praveen)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is being done in a background page, you have to make sure the authentication is being done in another page because the background page is headless, there is no UI. So how would the user click on authorize?

I don't know the Facebook API, but since it is OAuth2, what I would do is create a separate html page called, "facebook_auth.html" and you place the authentication code there. After it has been authorized, follow what ifaour stated. HE seems he knows what he is doing. Your background page will just open that new tab (chrome.tabs.create) to the authentication.

Take a look at this tutorial, and apply it to Facebook:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html